# can anyone fix this. jQuery $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a form like this (already add jquery latest)

```
echo '<form name="chat" id="chat" action="/pages/guicsdl.php" method="post">'; 
echo bbcode::auto_bb('chat', 'text'); 
echo '<textarea rows="3" name="text" id="text"></textarea><br/>'; 
echo '<input type="hidden" name="trave" value="'.$trave.'" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Gửi" /></form>';
```

and the js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("chat").submit(function(){ 
        $.post('/pages/guicsdl.php', $("#chat").serialize() ); 
    }); 
});
```

and the file guicsdl.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $noidung = functions::check($_POST['text']); 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `status` SET `user_id`='".$user_id."', `text`='".$noidung."', `time`='".time()."'"); 
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `tongchat`= tongchat+1 WHERE id = '".$user_id."' ");
    $trave = isset($_POST['trave']) ? base64_decode($_POST['trave']) : '';     
    header("Location: $trave"); 
}
```

i only want when i submit the form, the page doesn't refresh, the data insert to database. can any one help me fix? pls, and thanks. sorry for bad english.

Comment: Add `return false;` to the submission thing.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59

Comment: how? pls edit that code.

Comment: $("chat").submit(...) should be  $("#chat").submit(...)

Comment: i had added that. but when i submit, the page refresh and nothing insert to database. what i wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `return false;` so that the browser 'understands' that it should not submit the form directly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#chat").submit(function(){ 
        $.post('/pages/guicsdl.php', $("#chat").serialize() ); 

        return false;
    });
});
```

Another way (which I myself prefer) is to tell the event to not do it's default behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#chat").submit(function(ev){  // note the extra parameter
        ev.preventDefault();

        $.post('/pages/guicsdl.php', $("#chat").serialize() ); 
    });
});
```

Wilmer also noticed that you had forgotten to put a `#` for the jQuery identifier when selecting the chat form.

Comment: I would also change the post to: `$.post(this.action, $(this).serialize())` then if they change the html they won't need to change the js too

Comment: i had added. but nothing gonna change. the page just refreshing and nothing insert to database. can you fix the $.post?